# Unknown Windows Message 0xC052

Tags: .net, winforms, message-loop

I'm working on a problem ([How to Detect a form open inside the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690011/how-to-detect-a-form-open-inside-the-application)) and stumbled over a Windows Message I can't understand: 0xC052.

This is the first Message I receive in a MessageFilter when a form opens. But since I didn't found any reference I don't want to rely on the assumption, that the message tells me reliable that a form was opened.

**EDIT:** Added code

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(new MessageFilterImpl());

class MessageFilterImpl : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        Control wnd = Form.FromHandle(m.HWnd);
        if (wnd is Form)
            knownForms.Add((Form)wnd); //m.Msg is 0xC052

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like something broadcasted from another application you have installed - it's not a standard message. In any case, what you're looking for is the `Load` event, I think.

Comment: Thanks. But to add an event handler to the `Load`-event I'd need to know the `form` in the first place, which is the initial problem.

Comment: It may be an Unicode of any character.

Comment: Why should a unicode-character be the message-code inside the message-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a well-formed windows message, it's a dynamically allocated ID  returned from the [RegisterWindowMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947(v=vs.85).aspx) function (note the range `0xC000-0xFFFF`). The function is used when you need to define a new windows message that's supposed to be system-unique. In other words, *you can't rely on the ID* - it will be different the next time you reboot.

.NET Winforms uses it internally plenty of times - it's a well behaving windows application framework. So the exact number you found might conceivably correspond to something like:

- A thread callback (`Invoke` and friends)
- Mouse enter message
- Get control name (`Name`)

And of course, it doesn't even have to be a .NET message - there might be some application on your system that broadcasts messages to all forms, for example. It's a common way of handling RPC (in my case, the form received e.g. `MSUIM.Msg.RpcSendReceive`).